# Cap Framerate in the asynchronous world of Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a game in JavaScript & HTML5 with CreateJS. (**I doubt you'll need CreateJS experience to answer this question, though**)

My main game loop function is initialized and run using the CreateJS library like so:

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", loop);
```

(Similar to an event handler)

Then, it's off to the races - my function loops indefinitely, running my game at around 50FPS.

**I want to cap this at 30FPS.** But without a "sleep" function, or any real "pause" function, what's the best way to do that? How can I force my loop to slow down?

Thanks!
-W

Comment: Have you considered [using a fixed timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) for your simulation, then letting the display continue to run at the maximum framerate it can (eg. via [RequestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html):

`Ticker.framerate = 30;`

Hope that helps.